# Different coordinates in mapbox maps in relation with google maps?

Tags: google-maps, mapbox

I've changed a directory site with google maps to mapbox map, due to the payment policy of google...Everything is okay but the same coordinates of poi in google maps are in different places on mapbox maps? Why? Is there any formula to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it's simple....Coordinates are in reverse in both cases....

lat, long --> long, lat....

Comment: It's really strange thing, but that's right :)

Thanks